# UpdatePanel in Asp.NET postback on enter key press

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

Hello there I have an `updatepanel` setup. I have set its update mode to be conditional so that it only fires when the trigger events happens. Inside the `updatepanel` I have set the triggers to be some image controls and the event name to be click. Everything's fine till now.

But now I have also a `textbox` setup. When ever I enter some other text and press enter it causes the postback and the update panel takes control. Even though I have set the `autoPostBack` property of the `textbox` to be false and the `updatePanel` `UpdateMode` to be Conditional. Could somebody please point out the problem. What am I doing wrong? I only want the `updatepanel` to take charge when the trigger events occur for this `updatePanel`

Here's my code for `updatepanel` and `textBox` . .

```
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ImageButtonLeftArrow" EventName="click" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ImageButtonRightArrow" EventName="click" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>

                <asp:AdRotator ID="AdRotator1" runat="server"
                AdvertisementFile="~/MainImages.xml" Height="650" Width="934" 
                onadcreated="AdRotator1_AdCreated" CssClass="borderClassForAdRotator" />

                <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" >
                    <ProgressTemplate>
                        <div >
                        <img src="images/loading.gif" class="overLayImage" />
                        </div>
                    </ProgressTemplate>
                </asp:UpdateProgress>

            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
 <asp:TextBox ID="search" CssClass="search" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: could you please post the complete html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a `submit` button setup too on the page? Hitting enter is causing the form submit and hence, UpdatePanel could be performing the update.

If you're not sure, post your full HTML and JS here.

**Update:** Also, if this is the only textbox on the page, the Submit on Enter is the default behavior. In that case, add a eventhandler to cancel the default behvior like this:

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function disableSubmitOnEnter(e)
     {
         var key;      
         if(window.event)
               key = window.event.keyCode; //IE
          else
               key = e.which; //firefox      

         return (key != 13);
     }
</script>
```

**codebehind:**

```
search.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return disableSubmitOnEnter();");
```

Comment: No theres no submit button on the page.

Comment: Can you post full HTML and JS? There must be something that does the submit on Enter.

Comment: well sir the Html in very not very neat ! but im going to edit the post for you

Comment: Why is it not working. Pressing enter should not trigger the updatePanel! Please help me out

Comment: Sorry. Updated my answer. Check the codebehind part. Here's a working sample: http://www.coderun.com/ide/?w=VyV8JtGCi06zhHgi9zoKEA

Answer (score 0):

Use a Javascript function for the onkeydown event and if it's the enter key just return false. (the enter key is keycode 13)

```
if(event.keycode == 13) return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the above answers does not work, use this single line code.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="search" CssClass="search" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" onkeydown = "return (event.keyCode!=13);" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your `TextBox` in a `UpdatePanel` and set the `AutoPostBack` property of the `TextBox` to **true**. This method worked for me.